# Start Button to enable and resume an animation without repeating the function again when double clicked (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I have created 2 buttons start and stop for particle simulation along a particular path.

```
<button onclick="start()" id="myButton">Start</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

When I click start an animation function runs and when I stop, the animation stops and again when I click start it resumes from the same position where it stopped. My problem is that when I click start button when the animation is running, the animation loop repeats and hence the speed of the particles increases every time I click start.

animate is the function that runs when I click start. I tried setting the attribute to disable but it disables the start button completely after the first click but I want to use it to resume my animation.

```
function start() {

  requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 //var disable=document.getElementById("myButton").setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
}

function stop() {
  if (requestId){
        clearTimeout(timeInterval);
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
        requestId = 0;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Store the animations state in a variable, and check that before initiating the animation:

```
var running = false;

function start() {
    if (running) {
        return;
    }
    requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    running = true;
}

function stop() {
    if (requestId) {
        clearTimeout(timeInterval);
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
        running = false;
        requestId = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but if I click stop and then start button again, it does not resume from the position where it stopped. The start button has been completely disabled.

Comment: can you verify that running is being set to false in the stop function?

Comment: I have set running=false in stop function and the start button becomes completely disabled  after the first click.